# USB-3–Lightning cable: Does it yet exist?

Tags: ipad, usb, lightning

According to Apple, the 2017 iPad Pros (12.9 and 10.5 inch) are equipped with a USB-3–capable Lightning connector and Apple already sells a [Lightning to USB 3 camera adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-to-usb-3-camera-adapter).

However, I am looking for an USB-3–Lightning cable to connect the iPad at full speed to my MacBook Pro.

Does such a cable already exist?

Background:
I am using my 12.9 inch 2017 iPadPro as a versatile secondary display connected via Apple's USB-C–Lightning to my Macbook Pro 2017. The MacOS / iPad software stack is [Duet Display](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-to-usb-3-camera-adapter).

All this works pretty well, however, the secondary display has a nondramatic, but noticeable lag. I assume that the USB-2 connection (max 480 MBit) is the bottleneck here.

Comment: you seem to be using USB-3 and USB-C interchangeably. The former uses the standard USB plug, the latter uses a new smaller connector. Are you looking for a "3" to "C" adapter or a USB-C to Lightning cable or something else I may not be understanding?

Comment: @SteveChambers: Thanks Steve! I am looking for a Lightning cable that supports USB 3 (5 GBit/s) or USB3.1V2 (10 GBit/s) transfer rates, regardless of the plug being type A or C. Unfortunately, my current cable (Apple's USB-C to Lightning cable) just provides USB 2 with 480 MBit/s.

Comment: @SteveChambers: Yes, as written in my question and comment **I have exactly this cable**. However, **despite the USB-C connector,  the original Apple USB-C to Lightning cable is an USB 2 cable** with only 480 MBit/s transfer speed. I am looking for an USB 3 cable.